# R How to call '[.class<-' directly

Tags: r

Out of curiosity, how would I call the '[.class' function in R directly?

I know that I can do:

```
test <- c(2,4,6)
test[2]
```

But would it be possible to specify the class directly? And if so, how?

```
'[.numeric<-'(test , 2)
'[.numeric'(test , 2)
```

I have tried these but they come back with

```
Error: could not find function "[.numeric"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[` is an [internal generic](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/OO-essentials#recognising-objects-generic-functions-and-methods), which means that dispatch occurs in C, and [base types](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/OO-essentials#base-types) (like numeric) don't have S3 methods in R. That's why there's no  `[.numeric` or `[<-.numeric`.

It's not clear exactly what you want, but for your example, you can just do

```
test <- 1:3
`[`(test, 2)
`[<-`(test, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Ah ok, I get it. And the generic function will resolve from the class of the object. So that is why this works too: 

    dtTest <- data.table(A=1:3, B=4:6); "["(dtTest, , list(B))

Comment: Minor clarification: dispatch for all types occurs in C, but dispatch to base types is handled directly in C, thus no methods written in R for base type classes.